# Provide sets that are an open ball in the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ induced by the following metric: $d(x,y) = \ln(1+|x-y|)$.

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the following metric: $d(x,y) = \ln(1+|x-y|)$. Open balls for a metric are defined for any $x \ in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon > 0 $ as: $B_d(x,\epsilon) = \{y \in \mathbb{Z}\ s.t.\  d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$.

I'm given a couple of options for sets that are open ball in the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ induced by $d$, but I'm not sure where to begin to determine if they are or are not correct: $\{0,1,2,3\}$, $\{–300,–299,–298\}$, $\{–3,–2,–1,0,1,2,3\}$, and $\{…,–3,–2,–1\}$.

The radius of the ball must be large enough so that the open ball can encompass the set, so I don't see how the last work. But the other three I'm just not sure. Was wondering if someone could help explain this... thanks.

Comment: $$ d(x,y) \lt \epsilon\iff |x-y|\lt e^{\epsilon}-1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c\in \Bbb Z$, $\epsilon>0$. Then 
$$B_d(c,r)=\{a\in\Bbb Z:\ln(1+|a-c|)<r\}=\{a\in\Bbb Z:|a-c|<e^r-1\}$$

Since $e^r-1$ can be any positive real number, these balls and the "usual" balls are exactly the same. Namely, if you define $B(c,s)=\{a\in\Bbb Z:|a-c|<s\}$, we have
$$B_d(c,r)=B(c,e^r-1)$$
$$B(c,s)=B_d(c,\ln(1+s))$$

Comment: Are the metrics [equivalent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics) though? I'm not sure that I find $\alpha |x-y|\leq d(x,y)=\ln(1+|x-y|)$?

Answer (score 1):

As ajotaxte observed, there's no difference in topology between this metric and the simpler $|x-y|$, do I'll use that metric instead. As you noted, the last interval is too big to have a radius, so it can't be a ball. Another salient property of balls is *symmetry* - the ball must extend the same distance in each direction from the center. Your first example, $\{0,1,2,3\}$, can't have a center - if the center were $2$, for example, the radius would be more than $2$ on the left and less than $2$ on the right, otherwise $4$ would be included.

On the other hand, consider for example $\{0,1,2\} $. Here, we can take the center to be 1 and the radius $1.5$.

Comment: Which makes sense so the middle two examples, $\{–300,–299,–298\}$ and $\{–3,–2,–1,0,1,2,3\}$ work, as would something much larger like $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$, right?

Comment: @Learner Right. Can you see the general rule?

Comment: Yes- these 2 answers combined is extremely helpful! Thank you both!